# Auto suggesion in Input box not working in second Input box on same page in WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, autocomplete, autosuggest

I am making an auto suggesion input box in my WordPress site. It is perfectly working for one Input box but not working for the second box on same page.
Here is my code.
In function.php of the child theme.

```
    function mysite_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('autocomplete', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.auto-complete.js', array('jquery'));

    wp_enqueue_script('mysite-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/mysite.js', array('jquery', 'autocomplete'));

    wp_enqueue_style('autocomplete.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.auto-complete.css');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mysite_js');



add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_listing_names', 'ajax_listings');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_listing_names', 'ajax_listings');

function ajax_listings() {
    global $wpdb;


    $name = $wpdb->esc_like(stripslashes($_POST['name'])).'%'; //escape for use in LIKE statement
    $sql = "select post_title 
        from $wpdb->posts 
        where post_title like %s 
        and post_type='portfolio' and post_status='publish'";

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $name);

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    //copy the business titles to a simple array
    $titles = array();
    foreach( $results as $r )
        $titles[] = addslashes($r->post_title);

    echo json_encode($titles); 

    die(); 
}
```

as you can see I've used mysite.js file for my jquery. The code of this file is..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('#ews-search').autoComplete({
        source: function(name, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('#ews-search1').autoComplete({
        source: function(name, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#content .ews-search-class').attr('id','ews-search1');
});
```

and the HTML for input box is

```
<input name="ofsearch" placeholder="Region" value="shag" id="ews-search" class="ews-search-class" autocomplete="off" style="" type="text">
    <div id="content">
    <input name="ofsearch" placeholder="Region" value="shag" id="ews-search1" class="ews-search-class" type="text"></div>
```

now what I am actually trying to do is, I changed the ID of the second input box using jQuery since both the input box are coming from the same short code with same ID so I changed the ID of the second box using jQuery. 
Here is the [link](http://devwp.batapartments.co/?s=shag&post_types=portfolio) of the page I am working. Please help.

Comment: _“I changed the ID of the second input box using jQuery”_ - where and when are you doing that? Of course that would need to happen, before `$('#ews-search1')` is executed.

Comment: Thank you so much. You just gave me the solution. Now It is working. I changed mysite.js .
I was changing the ID of the second input box after executing `$('#ews-search1')` .

Answer (score 0):

It worked after just a minor change in mysite.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   

    $('#ews-search').autoComplete({
        source: function(name, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#content .ews-search-class').attr('id','ews-search1');
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   

    $('#ews-search1').autoComplete({
        source: function(name, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: 'action=get_listing_names&name='+name,
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```